# Can you identify this Starship?

Tags: star-trek, object-identification

I found this photo on the web:

[image: Star Trek Starships]

Can you please identify the highlighted starship? What is its name? What is its class? When did it appear in canon? Or, is this just a non-canonical artistic creation?

**My Approach:** From the saucer design, it's an Earth vessel. As the other one is Kirk's ship (from design), it's from the 23rd century. From the graphics quality, it's not from TOS. It's most likely from the 2009 Star Trek movie, but I didn't see that starship in the movie (or, if I did I've forgotten it).

Comment: More downvotes, please. Its really a poor question. The first Earth vessel displayed in 2009 Star Trek movie was USS Kelvin and its design slipped from my mind.

Comment: There are those in the universe who have NOT seen the new ST movie. For them it's a perfectly interesting and valid question.

Comment: @DVK While I agree that for those that haven't seen the new ST movie it is a perfectly reasonable question, he mentions in the question that he has seen the movie...which makes it poorly researched.

Comment: I feel sad for those who haven't seen it.  They are missing a truly great movie.

Comment: @NominSim - "perfect visual memory" != "researched". Unless Google could have identified the ship from the image, I don't see how this could be "researched"

Comment: @DVK True, but he knew it was "most likely from the 2009 Star Trek movie", and a google search of "ships from the 2009 Star Trek movie" results in many images of the ship in question

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The highlighted ship is the [U.S.S. Kelvin](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Kelvin) from the 2009 Star Trek movie, tailing behind it is the U.S.S. Enterprise. As they never appeared on screen together, I assume it is just a superimposition of the two together, and/or an artists rendition of the two together.

The USS Kelvin ([aft view](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kelvin_type?file=USS_Kelvin,_aft.jpg))
[image]

Comment: Or another ship of the same class which did survive?

Answer (score -1):

looks like the Diligent from the original series, the class is Diligent as well 
[image: http://www.starscape.org.uk/gallery/st_pic008.jpg]

Comment: Is there anything to confirm this hypothesis or do you just guess because they look the same?

Comment: That ship did not appear in the original series.

Comment: @KeithThompson - It comes from a series of fan-art pictures; http://www.starscape.org.uk/gallery_trek3.php "*All images in these galleries have been created by me, please do not post them on other websites without linking back to this website.*"

Comment: Based on the 1970s vintage *Star Trek Technical Manual* the *Diligent* is either a scout or destroyer.  Kelvin was a destroyer, but the overall layout was extremely similar -- single warp nacelle below the saucer, and either no secondary hull or a small one above.